# MySQL timediff on one column for selected records in table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, datediff, timedelta

Basically what I am trying to do is fetch call duration based on SIP signalling.

I have a table with records as shown below and I am trying to write a SELECT statement that returns the following:

```
id  callid  date                    micro_ts            method  duration1   duration2
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
25  123     2016-04-05 00:00:25     1459814425000320    BYE     00:00:04    3.999876
46  234     2016-04-05 00:01:25     1459814485000000    BYE     00:00:04    4.000000
```

The ID is from first BYE for a given CallID. CallID is always the same for each individual call. 00:00:04 should be the difference between **date** and 3.999876 the difference between **micro_ts**.

The SQL should return one record per callid.
The tricky part here is that I am trying to get the difference between the messages indicating start/stop of the call.

I want it to return duration based on "The first method = 200 after method = 183 until first BYE" or "The first method = 200 after method = 180 and no method = 183 is found until first BYE"

How can I combine these criterias to return what I want for a table containing several calls?

I have been trying to write SQL as such:

```
select * from (
select id, callid, micro_ts, method, min(date) as StartTime, max(date) as EndTime,
timediff(max(date), min(date)) as duration
from (select t.*,
             (select count(*)
              from tableA t2
              where t2.date <= t.date and
                    t2.method = 'BYE'
             ) as grp
      from tableA t
     ) t where t.method = '200'
group by callid, method
order by 3 desc) z;
```

I believe this works under the assumption all calls only has 200 once and then a BYE.

```
id  callid  date                    micro_ts            method
---------------------------------------------------------------
1   123     2016-04-05 00:00:01     1459814401000025    INVITE
2   123     2016-04-05 00:00:02     1459814402000123    407
3   123     2016-04-05 00:00:03     1459814403000941    INVITE
4   123     2016-04-05 00:00:04     1459814404000392    INVITE
5   123     2016-04-05 00:00:05     1459814405000539    INVITE
6   123     2016-04-05 00:00:06     1459814406000101    404
7   123     2016-04-05 00:00:07     1459814407000007    INVITE
8   123     2016-04-05 00:00:08     1459814408000948    404
9   123     2016-04-05 00:00:09     1459814409000784    100
10  123     2016-04-05 00:00:10     1459814410000192    183
11  123     2016-04-05 00:00:11     1459814411000482    183
12  123     2016-04-05 00:00:12     1459814412000561    183
13  123     2016-04-05 00:00:13     1459814413000392    183
14  123     2016-04-05 00:00:14     1459814414000751    180
15  123     2016-04-05 00:00:15     1459814415000012    180
16  123     2016-04-05 00:00:16     1459814416000384    180
17  123     2016-04-05 00:00:17     1459814417000498    180
18  123     2016-04-05 00:00:18     1459814418000533    183
19  123     2016-04-05 00:00:19     1459814419000841    183
20  123     2016-04-05 00:00:20     1459814420000492    183
21  123     2016-04-05 00:00:21     1459814421000444    200         * FIRST 200 after 183
22  123     2016-04-05 00:00:22     1459814422000901    200         |
23  123     2016-04-05 00:00:23     1459814423000294    ACK         |
24  123     2016-04-05 00:00:24     1459814424000732    ACK         |
25  123     2016-04-05 00:00:25     1459814425000320    BYE         * FIRST BYE
26  123     2016-04-05 00:00:26     1459814426000020    BYE
27  123     2016-04-05 00:00:27     1459814427000391    200
28  123     2016-04-05 00:00:28     1459814428000123    200
29  234     2016-04-05 00:01:01     1459814461000000    INVITE
30  234     2016-04-05 00:01:02     1459814462000000    407
31  234     2016-04-05 00:01:03     1459814463000000    INVITE
32  234     2016-04-05 00:01:04     1459814464000000    INVITE
33  234     2016-04-05 00:01:05     1459814465000000    INVITE
34  234     2016-04-05 00:01:06     1459814466000000    404
35  234     2016-04-05 00:01:07     1459814467000000    INVITE
36  234     2016-04-05 00:01:08     1459814468000000    404
37  234     2016-04-05 00:01:09     1459814469000000    100
38  234     2016-04-05 00:01:10     1459814470000000    183
39  234     2016-04-05 00:01:11     1459814471000000    183
40  234     2016-04-05 00:01:12     1459814472000000    183
41  234     2016-04-05 00:01:13     1459814473000000    183
42  234     2016-04-05 00:01:14     1459814474000000    180
43  234     2016-04-05 00:01:15     1459814475000000    180
44  234     2016-04-05 00:01:16     1459814476000000    180
45  234     2016-04-05 00:01:17     1459814477000000    180
46  234     2016-04-05 00:01:21     1459814481000000    200         * FIRST 200 after 180 whern no 183 is present
47  234     2016-04-05 00:01:22     1459814482000000    200         |
48  234     2016-04-05 00:01:23     1459814483000000    ACK         |
49  234     2016-04-05 00:01:24     1459814484000000    ACK         |
50  234     2016-04-05 00:01:25     1459814485000000    BYE         * FIRST BYE
51  234     2016-04-05 00:01:26     1459814486000000    BYE
52  234     2016-04-05 00:01:27     1459814487000000    200
53  234     2016-04-05 00:01:28     1459814488000000    200
```

Comment: You've said you are working on the assumption theres only 1 200 call, but in both places you highlighted 200, theres a 200 on the line below from the same callID. Canyou make an any assumptions such as the same call ID wont happen in a minute, but that the bye response will be done in < 1 minute?

Comment: Hello @BugFinder - My SQL example uses this assumption but I want this changed. The assumption is that there will only appear 200 for each CallID when a call is answered. That assumption will not always be valid. I want it to return duration based on "The first method = 200 after method = 183 until first BYE" or "The first method = 200 after method = 180 and no method = 183 is found until first BYE"

Comment: Let me try to rephrase.. "Duration between 200 and BYE for unique CallIDs when 200 appears after 183, or 180 if 183 is missing, and before BYE"

Comment: How quickly can callIDs get reused?

Comment: According to RFC 3261 it -can- be reused for each call as the RFC states it must be unique "across space and time for each seperate calls/sessions". In this particular case it will not be reused but if you have a solution that can take a combination of callID,from_user,to_user,date (all those fields are not included in the example) it's even better. I will accept both :)

Comment: Ok, so what unique fields do you have you havent yet mentioned.. And can we index stuff?

Comment: @AndyThompson, your logic around method 200, 180, 183 is not clear. Can it be reworded like the following? The call starts at the first occurrence of the two **consecutive** rows with either `method=183, then method=200` OR `method=180, then method=200`. In other words, the call starts at the first row when `method=200` AND the immediate previous row has `method in (180, 183)`. (row order is defined by the `id` column)

Comment: A call starts if there is a 200 after either 183, or after 180 if 183 is not present. There can be numerous 180/183 but at least one must exist. The immediate previous row does not have to be 180/183.

Comment: @BugFinder We can index. There are no other unique fields that are not yet mentioned.

Comment: I have a few ideas but they seem incredibly messy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a go and there may be some casting issues with the CASE expressions, but this should get you most of the way there:

```
SELECT id,
      callid
      start_date,
      start_ms,
      end_date,
      end_ms,
      end_date - start_date AS duration1,
      end_ms - start_ms AS duration2
 FROM (
   SELECT 
          @same_call := @callid = callid,
          @has_ended := @same_call AND (@has_ended OR @has_bye) AS has_ended,
          @has_18x := (@has_18x AND @same_call) OR method IN ('180','183'),
          @has_200 := (@has_200 AND @same_call) OR (@has_18x AND method = '200'),
          @has_bye := (@has_bye AND @same_call) OR (@has_200 AND method = 'BYE') AS has_bye,

          @start_date := CASE 
                           WHEN @has_200 THEN COALESCE(@start_date, `date`)
                         END AS start_date,
          @start_ms := CASE 
                         WHEN @has_200 THEN COALESCE(@start_ms, micro_ts)
                       END AS start_ms,
          @end_date := CASE 
                         WHEN @has_bye THEN COALESCE(@end_date, `date`)
                       END AS end_date,
          @end_ms := CASE 
                       WHEN @has_bye THEN COALESCE(@end_ms, micro_ts)
                     END AS end_ms,

          id,
          @callid := callid AS callid           

    FROM sip_signal

    JOIN (
      SELECT @callid := NULL,
             @has_ended := FALSE,
             @has_18x := FALSE,
             @has_200 := FALSE,
             @has_bye := FALSE,
             @start_date := NULL,
             @start_ms := NULL,
             @end_date := NULL,
             @end_ms := NULL                
         ) init

ORDER BY callid, micro_ts

      ) sip_call
WHERE has_bye 
  AND NOT has_ended
```

If you'd like to see the inner workings, just run the inner SELECT (+ the JOIN and ORDER BY) on it's own.

Comment: That works like a charm - and gives correct durations if you change "end_date - start_date as duration1" to include a timediff and the @has_200 and @has_bye for _ms to `micro_ts`. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'd also like to add it was nicely written and understandable for us non-experts. Pure gold.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have mySQL to hand.. so, this could be serious rubbish
but this is whats in my head I wanted to write it down before it ran away - as I said, it seems messy

```
select callid, ,datediff(data,case when start1<=start2 then start1 else start2 end) as duration from 
   (select callid,call_from,call_to,min(starta) as start1,min(startb) as start2,min(data) from 
        (select callid,call_from,call_to,
          count(case when method = 180 THEN date END) starta,
          count(case when method = 183 THEN date END) startb,
          count(case when method = 200 THEN date END) data,
        from mydata) group by callid, call_from,call_to))
```

Does this help? does this give you ideas?